# com.google.firebase.auth.firebaseautInvalidUserException: there is no user corresponding to this identifier

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

the issue is in case of forgotpassword reset email.  I first checked whether the email is present in firebase without writing the code for sending reset mail.Then i write reset code mail it is shows  Toastmessage while running app as invaliduserexception.No such Record.

```
package com.example.loginapp;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_forgot_password);
    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        forgotenteredmail=findViewById(R.id.forgotenteredmail);
    forgotnextbutton=findViewById(R.id.forgotnextbutton);
    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    forgotnextbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!validateemail() )
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                isUser();
                


            }

        }
    });


}

private Boolean validateemail ()
{
    String val=forgotenteredmail.getEditText().getText().toString();

    if(val.isEmpty()){
        forgotenteredmail.setError("The Field Cannot be Empty");
        return false;

    }
    else{
        forgotenteredmail.setError(null);
        forgotenteredmail.setErrorEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }
}


private  void  isUser() {
     email = forgotenteredmail.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();


    rootnode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    reference = rootnode.getReference("users");


    final Query checkuser = reference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email);
    checkuser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                forgotenteredmail.setError(null);
                forgotenteredmail.setErrorEnabled(false);

                resetUserPassword(email);
            } else {
                forgotenteredmail.setError("User does not Exist");
                forgotenteredmail.requestFocus();
            }
        }




        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}

public void resetUserPassword(String email){
    
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(forgotPassword.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("verifying..");
    progressDialog.show();
    
    mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reset password instructions has sent to your email",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Email don't exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });}
```

}

the problem occurs when sending reset mail

firebase database

```
 - **-appname**
    **-users**
            -username
                   -name:
                   -email
                   -username[enter image description here][1]
                   -passs
                   -phone
            -username
                  -name
```

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
       "users":{
          ".indexOn":"email"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What specific line in the code you shared shows what exact error?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  While debugging it doesnot show any erroor,but while running the app,checking for whether the email exist is show Invalid user exception as toast message

Comment: Instead of showing that message as a toast, can you log it and then copy paste the exact message (and any stack trace) from the logcat output into your question (there's an edit link right under it)?

Comment: PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding '".indexOn": "email"' at users to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance  :@FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.loginapp.forgotPassword$2.onDataChange(forgotPassword.java:105)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:179)
        at  
 com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:75)  @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0):

That message comes from:

```
reference=rootnode.getReference("users");
final Query checkuser=reference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email);
checkuser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    ...
```

The error message is quite explicit about the problem and solution:

> Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding '".indexOn": "email"' at users to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance

To solve the problem you need to add an index to your database's security rules as described in the documentation on [indexing your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data).

Something like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": "email"
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Update**: since you're having trouble getting this to work, I created an example in this jsbin: https://jsbin.com/kevafej/edit?js,console

The data under node `63097781` is:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "abc" : {
      "email" : "abc@acme.org"
    },
    "def" : {
      "email" : "def@acme.org"
    }
  }
}
```

The relevant code:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("63097781");

ref.child('users')
  .orderByChild('email')
  .equalTo('abc@acme.org')
  .once('value')
  .then(function(results) {
    results.forEach((snapshot)=>{
      console.log(snapshot.val());
    })
  })
```

If I set the rules for node `63097781` to:

```
"63097781": { 
  ".read": true
}
```

I get the correct node (`{ email: "abc@acme.org" }`), but with this warning:

> FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "email" at /63097781/users to your security rules for better performance.

If I then change the rules to (adding exactly what is said in the warning message):

```
"63097781": { 
  ".read": true, 
  "users": { 
    ".indexOn": "email" 
  }
}
```

With these rules we get the same results, but without the warning.

Comment: Even after adding indexon ,it still shows that message@FrankVanPuffelen

Comment: That seems unexpected. Can you update your question to show how you defined the index?

Comment: while dedugging     'mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).....'     this shows the invalid userexception that the ethe record not found...   I updated index as    '{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
       "users":{
          ".indexOn":"email"
    }
  }
  
  
  }'           @FrankVanPuffelen

Comment: Please edit your question, instead of providing this information in comments. There's an `edit` link right under it for this purpose.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem you're having, so added a working sample to my answer. Hopefully that helps you find the problem, or at least shows that the solution is what I outlined: adding the index to the `users` node. If you continue to have problems, can you set up a similar reproduction in a jsbin of your problem? This will require that you rewrite the code in JavaScript, for which you can use my jsbin as an example.

Comment: The problem has solved.I get reset password mail and updated the password.ABLE sign in using the new password.But the password is not updated in the database

Comment: Sending a password reset email is completely unrelated to querying and creating indexes in your database. For future questions I recommend isolating the problem to just one Firebase product, as the error message you posted in the comments to your question is going to be fixed by the rules I posted in my answer.